# Insert in between two rows and re-serial the nos

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, cursor

Ho to insert record between two records and update the list in serial order in to the SQL Server database using cursor?

e.g: total 5 record i want to insert at after 3rd row and newly added row will set to 4th and 4th, 5th row will get the serial number 5 & 6.

Comment: And what does the table look like please? Is it IDENTITY? What defines order now?

Comment: Rows in an SQL database table don't *have* an inherent order. If you need some kind of sequence number, it's usually better to compute this during `SELECT` rather than storing it in the database. Are there some other columns within the row that could be used to compute this ordering? (There probably are, if you've decide the new row should be the 4th)

Answer (score 3):

In principle there are no such thing as 'between two records' in SQL - native record order is not declared. You should query data in whatever order you need.

What about second part of your question - updating serial numbers, then you have two options.

First is to use not integer, but float values for ordering, this way you can use value 3.5, which returns newly added row between 3 and 4, when query is ordered by this field.

Second one is to increase all serial numbers, greater than 3 in your case and insert new record after that:

```
Update mytable Set serialno=serialno+1 Where serialno > @lastnumbertokeep
Insert Into mytable (serialno, otherfields) Values (@lastnumbertokeep+1, othervalues)
```

For 5 records and one user at a time that is not problem; for million records and 10 simultaneous updates this locks database for long time and can cause nasty side effects.

Comment: I want to Insert Record between two records using Cursor in Stored procedure.How to insert record between two records and update the list in serial order in to the SQL Server database using cursor?

e.g: total 5 record i want to insert at after 3rd row and newly added row will set to 4th and 4th, 5th row will get the serial number 5 & 6.

Comment: @Shektar: you are ignoring the answer. Read the first sentence of the answer again.

Comment: @Shekhar Shete India: Maybe you can show some of your code, particulary to explain your need for updateable/insertable CURSOR? I usually deal with tables directly, thereby I could overlook some aspects of your question.

Comment: TableFields:[ControlChartID],[LineNumber],[ConstituencyNumber],PartNumber],FromVoterNumber],[ToVoterNumber],TotalVoters]